# A problem with react component(view) not updating but the state is updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I am facing a bit of a problem. I have two components. One parent component that is called goals and under different instances of goal. I am updating state of the parent component by passing a function to its children. The state of the parent is updated however only one of the child who made the change apply the change they should be all the same

Goals

```js
import UserGoal from "./UserGoal";
import { Button, Container, Form, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./UserGoal.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const UserGoals = () => {
  var test = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Marriage",
    icon: "Marriage.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Car",
    icon: "Car.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Home",
    icon: "Home.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Education",
    icon: "Education.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Travel",
    icon: "Travel.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Retirement",
    icon: "Retirement.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Other",
    icon: "Other.png",
    isSelected:false,
    style: "goal-category"
  },
  
]
 
const [goals, setGoals] = useState(test)

  const changeSelection = (id) => {
    
    const newarr = goals.map((GoalType)=> {
      if(GoalType.id===id){
        GoalType.isSelected=true
        GoalType.style= "goal-category2"
      }
      else {
        GoalType.isSelected=false
        GoalType.style= "goal-category"
        }
        return GoalType
    })
    forceUpdate(newarr)
    console.log(goals);
    
  }

  const forceUpdate = React.useCallback((arr) => {
      setGoals(arr);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Your saving goal</h1>
      <div className="goal-categories">
        {goals.map((GoalType) => (
          <UserGoal
            id={GoalType.id}
            name={GoalType.name}
            icon={GoalType.icon}
            isSelected={()=>GoalType.isSelected}
            style={()=>GoalType.style}
            key={GoalType.id}
            onClick={changeSelection}
          ></UserGoal>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="reg-wrapper">
        <div className="reg-inner">
          <Form className="ctr-form">
            <Form.Label>Amount</Form.Label>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <Form.Control
                className="input"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0.00"
              />
              <div className="input-group-text">SAR</div>
            </InputGroup>
            <Form.Label>Date</Form.Label>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <Form.Control className="input" type="date" />
            </InputGroup>
            <div className="btn">
              <Link to="/expenses">
                <Button id="btn btn-primary" className="dbtn">
                  Next
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default UserGoals
```

Goal

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./UserGoal.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function UserGoal({ id, name, icon, isSelected, style, onClick }) {
  const [style_, setStyle_] = useState(style())
  return (
    <>
      <div className="goal-category-container">
        <div
          onClick={()=>{
            onClick(id);
            setStyle_(style())
          }}
          className={style_}
        >
          <div className="icon-wrap">
            <img src={"assets/" + icon} alt="Goal Icon" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="category-name">{name} </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call setStyle_ immediately after the callback, even though the effects of the callback are asynchronous. Ie, the style won't be updated yet because the patent is doing an asynchronous setState.

Instead send down style as a value, not a function. That way the child will react to updates. Also having style as state oh the child is unnecessary, since you can just rely on the prop.

Also, don't use mutation in your map function. Instead create new goal objects. And your React.useCallback is equivalent to using the setter directly, it can be removed.